# dos llaves foráneas en la misma tabla? o que significan estos simbolos del diagrama?

Tags: mysql

[image: los símbolos debajo de la primera tabla]

el metodo que use es este

```
CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES (
DNI varchar(8),
NomApels nvarchar(255),
DNIJEfe varchar(8),
Despacho int ,
primary key (DNI),
foreign key(Despacho) references DESPACHOS(Numero) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una tabla **autorreferenciada**. Este patrón de diseño se ve típicamente cuando tienes tablas que contienen datos con estructura jerárquica.

En el código de creación de tu tabla, falta esta llave foránea (sólo aparece la que se hace a la tabla `DESPACHOS`). Sin embargo, la llave foránea sería que la columna `DNIJefe` está referenciada a la columna `DNI` de la tabla `DIRECTORES`. Esto simplemente quiere decir que el jefe (o el nivel jerárquico superior) de un director, antes debe existir en la misma tabla `DIRECTORES` con su propio `DNI`.

Comment: @SebastianRivera sí, ese comentario está incluido en tu pregunta, no entiendo bien si estás preguntando algo más?

Comment: foreign key (DNI)references DESPACHOS(DNI) o foreign key (DNI)references (DNI) cual seria la correcta sintaxis?

Comment: No conozco los comandos de mysql, pero sí o sí sería DNIJefe con DNI

Comment: muchas gracias ...

Comment: la forma correcta:                                                                                                           CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES (
DNI varchar(8)  not null ,
NomApels nvarchar(255),
DNIJefe varchar(8)  null  ,
Despacho int ,
primary key (DNI),
 


foreign key (DNIJefe) references DIRECTORES(DNI) ,
foreign key (Despacho)references DESPACHOS(Numero)
);